# saving the data after it was printed to screen python

Tags: python

Is there a way to save data after it was printed to the screen? 
for example: 
lets have some arbitrary function

```
def main():
    if something:
       for i in range(n):
           output= "%f %f" %(n,d)
           print output

    if something:
       for i in range(n):
           output="%f %f" %(n,d)
           print output

    fileout=open("data.csv", "a")
    fileout.write(output)
```

this will only write the last data for the last range in for loop.

Edit: I want to ask a user if she/he wants to save that data

Comment: If you want `output` from both `if` branches, why not save it to file in both places?

Comment: how would i do it if i want to prompt the user if she/he wants to save a data to a file?

Comment: If it were me, I'd let the user redirect output to a file via standard shell `./program > filename` if they actually wanted it saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your output variable(s) at the highest level of scope in your program first.  This will allow it to be written to a file in the manner you've programmed.

If you want to prompt a user for a location to save the file(s), that's merely this:

```
out1 = raw_input("Where would you like to save this? ")
```

You can do the same for another output file variable.

Answer (score 1):

just use this in the if conditions:

```
print >>fileout, output #this will save the output to the data.csv file
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code...

1: If you really want to use print, change sys.stdout to a different stream

2: use files

## 1

```
import sys
oldstdout=sys.stdout
f=open("myfile","w")
sys.stdout=f

def main():
    if something:
        for i in range(n):
            print "%f %f"%(n,d)

        if something:
            for i in range(n):
                print "%f %f"%(n,d)
```

## 2

```
f=open("myfile","w")

def main():
    if something:
        for i in range(n):
            f.write("%f %f"%(n,d))

        if something:
            for i in range(n):
                f.write("%f %f"%(n,d))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (somewhat pathological) example that will let you both `print` and save the statements that you print in a global list (which we'll call `OUTPUT`):

```
import sys

OUTPUT = []

def print_wrapper(method):
    class result(object):

      def __init__(self, file_obj):
          self.file_obj = file_obj

      def __getattr__(self, name):
          return getattr(self.file_obj, name)

      def write(self, value):
          OUTPUT.append(value)
          return self.file_obj.write(value)

    return result(method)

original_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = print_wrapper(original_stdout)

# This will still print, but will add 'Hi' and '\n' to OUTPUT as well
print 'Hi'
# This will still print, but will add 'None' and '\n' to OUTPUT as well
print None
# This uses the original stdout to print, so won't change OUTPUT
original_stdout.write(repr(OUTPUT))
original_stdout.write('\n')
```

or you could alternately prepare yourself for Python 3 (or just use it) and wrap the `print` method itself:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # must have Python >= 2.6


OUTPUT = []


def wrap_print(method):
    def result(value):
        OUTPUT.append(value)
        return method(value)
    return result


old_print = print
print = wrap_print(old_print)

print('Hi')
print(None)
old_print(OUTPUT)
```